# This table has a column with check boxs that need to select the row and send rows to another table.

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to send the coils selected on "AuctionPage" to the another table on "MyBids" Page. I think it would be best to grab the coilID and pass it that way but not sure how? Any help would be appreciated.

AuctionPage-->

@model NucorPrototypes_V1.ViewModel.AuctionPage

@{

```
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
```

}

```
<title>Auction </title>
```

```
<div id="header" style="background-color: #008751">

    <h1 style="margin-bottom: 0; color: #FFFFFF">Secondary Coil Auction </h1>

</div>

<div id="content">

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <table id="myTable" border="3" style="background-color: #B0B0B0" cellpadding="10" class="table">

        <tr>

            <th>Select</th>

            <th>Serial Number</th>

            <th>Minimum Bid</th>

            <th>Current High Bid</th>

            <th>Grade</th>

            <th>Heat Number</th>

            <th>Gauge</th>

            <th>Width</th>

            <th>Weight</th>

            <th>Defect 1</th>

            <th>Defect 2</th>

            <th>Defect 3</th>

        </tr>

        @foreach (var item1 in Model.Coils)

        {

            <tr>

                <td>

                    <input type="checkbox" name="selection" id="@item1.Coil_ID" align="center">

                </td>

                <td>

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item1.Coil_ID)

                </td>

                <td>

                    @foreach (var item2 in Model.Auctions)

                    {

                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.Auc_MinBid)

                    }

                </td>




                <td>

                    @foreach (var item3 in Model.Bids)

                    {



                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item3.Bid_Amt)

                        //string sqlq = "select max(Bid_Amt) from Bid inner join AuctionItem ON Bid.Bid_ID = AuctionItem.Bid_ID where Coil_ID =" + item1.Coil_ID +"' '";



                    }




                </td>




                <td>

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item1.Coil_Grade)

                </td>

                <td>

                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item1.Coil_HeatNo)</a>

                    <!-- Modal -->

                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                            <div class="modal-content">

                                <div class="modal-header">

                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item1.Coil_HeatNo)</h4>

                                </div>

                                <div class="modal-body">



                                    CHemistries

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </td>

                <td>

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item1.Coil_Gauge)

                </td>

                <td>

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item1.Coil_Width)

                </td>

                <td>

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item1.Coil_Weight)

                </td>

                <td>

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item1.Coil_Defect1)

                </td>

                <td>

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item1.Coil_Defect2)

                </td>

                <td>

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item1.Coil_Defect3)

                </td>




            </tr>

        }




    </table>

    </center>

</div>

<center>
```

[Place Bid(s)](/Home/MyBids)

```
</center>
```

MyBids Page-->

@model NucorPrototypes_V1.ViewModel.MyBids

@{

```
ViewBag.Title = "MyBids";
```

}

Auction

Secondary Coil Auction 





    





Bid Amount per 100 weight

Remove Bid

Serial Number

Minimum Bid

Current High Bid

Grade

Heat Number

Gauge

Width

Weight

Defect 1

Defect 2

Defect 3








@foreach( var row in Model.Coils)

    {







 Remove Bid

    @Html.DisplayFor( modelItem => row.Coil_ID)



    }

```
<center>
```

Confirm Bids

Save as...

```
</center>
```

Comment: when you say send to another page.  Is this redirecting when they click on a row or do you collect all of the rows clicked when they post and redirect?

Comment: The rows are selected by a checkbox and then they click "Place Bids" button to send the rows to the My Bids page table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for getting the result of multiple check boxes I use Request.Form
on your controller

```
Request.Form["chkBoxName"].ToString();
```

make sure every check box has the same name (chxBoxName in this example) and it will give you a list of all of the check boxes that were selected.  You can then add those items to the next table on the controller and redirect there.  Hope this helps

Edit:

this will return a comma delimited list of the selected check boxes.  since you want to add them to another table you will need to query the database for them.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostBack(){
    Model model = new Model();
    List<Bids> bids = new List<Bids>();
    List<int> result = Request.Form["chkBoxName"].ToString().split(',');
    foreach(var id in result){
        //query the database to get the record for id
        bids.add("result of query");
    }
    Model.Bids = bids;
    return RedirectToAction("Bids", bids);
}
```

Comment: So in my Controller do I need to make a ActionResult with this Request.Form in it? What would I return? Thanks for the help this gives me a better understanding.

Comment: yes, when you post back your page put this in the action result method that is called.  You said redirect to another page so you would create the data table for the second page, include the selected rows,  and redirect there

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there anyway you could show me an example? I understand the context just not sure how to write it in code.

Comment: without knowing more about your code I can't get very exact but here is an example.  Hope it helps

Comment: So do I need to put my table in a @HTML.BeginForm in my index?

Comment: html.beginform puts a form tag on the page so anything you have on the page in a for helper (textboxfor, dropdownlistfor, etc) will post back to the controller.  Tables are generally for displaying so they won't post back easily.  It is a lot easier to just regenerate the table from the database

Answer (score 0):

Just put the checkboxes in a sub form where the action goes to the target form.  I don't see where the  statement is in the HTML you provided, but you can have multiple forms on the same page with differing targets.